# how to execute the correct paypal payment

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am implementing paypal payments within a node server. I create a payment using

```
paypal_api.payment.create(...);
```

The response contains a link for the user to go and confirm the payment at paypal.com. After the payment is confirmed the user is redirected to the return_url I specified in the payment details, along with a query string with a `PayerID` but no paymentID.

Suppose my server has several paypal payments waiting for user confirmation. How am I to know which payment to execute when the return_url is invoked if all the query string shows is the `PayerID`. Do I need to generate unique return_urls for each payment or is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  It should never interfere.  Each transaction would already have a unique PayPal token, and each shopper on the site would have a unique PayerID.  If you're using session variables or something like that there would be no interference.

Comment: To execute a paypal payment you need both the paymentID and the PayerID. After the user confirms the payment a request is sent to my server at `return_url/?PayerID=1234abcd`. This is the first moment I learn the `PayerID`. It seems since I need both the PaymentID and the PayerID tp execute a payment paypal should send both parameters in the query string. A work around is to specify a unique return_url for each payment that I can use to look-up the paymentID in my own database. Note that you have to specify the return_url before paypal assigns a paymentID.

Comment: Why not use session variables or save data to your database so you can pull it back out once you've returned from PayPal?  I've always used session vars and have never had any issues.

Comment: Yes I am currently storing the paymentID in my database. But it feels like a hack. If paypal would just send the paymentID along with PayerID in the query string this would be very simple.